# Using excel VBA to lookup cell value, and return multiple values based on that cell

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry for the terrible title, I didn't know how to summarise my problem.

I have a worksheet with a bunch of payments. Each payment is made to an ID number. I have another worksheet with the ID numbers and their breakdown; the percentage of the payment that should be allocated to each pot.

e.g

```
Client XYZ ,100 payment in worksheet one, has ID 123.
```

worksheet 2 has,

```
123 | A | 5%
 23 | B | 95%  and so on
```

I would like to be able to produce a third worksheet of the form.

```
XYZ, 123, A, $5
XYZ, 123, B, $95
```

So each payment is multiplied by its breakdown and displayed on another sheet along with the rest of the clients info in the adjoining columns.

Even just a start on this would be very helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: This seems like a simple lookup function. Have you considered using Access or another database package for this? It would seem to be a more appropriate tool for your purposes

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question it seems you just want to perform a simple lookup.

If you don't need to use VBA, you can do this easily [using excel's VLOOKUP function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear then. The 100 payment above need to be split into several payments, then this repeated for many individual payment. So say a 100 payment is made into pot id 123. Pot id is comprised of 5 subaccounts, that 100 needs to be split by the percentages of each of the subaccounts. 

So I want each row of the first worksheet to become 5 rows for example, with the 100 broken down into its subpayments.

Comment: Have you considered a pivot table?